# Python Minimizing a function until it equals a desired value

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I need to minimise a input value (x) until the ouput value (y) meets the desired value exactly or it is of by some decimals.
I know that I can use the scipy.optimisation.minimize function but I am having troubles to set it up properly.

```python
optimize_fun_test(100)
```

this is my written function which for a specific value (in this case price) calculates the margin i will have when I sell my product.

Now from my understanding I need to set a constraint which holds the minimum margin which I want to target, as my goal is to sell the product as cheap as possible but I need to have a minimum margin that I have to target, in order to be profitable.
So let's say that my function calculates a margin of 25% (0.25) when i sell my product for 100Euro, and my margin that I wish to target is 12.334452% (0.1233452), the price will be lower. So the minimize function should be able to find the exact price for which I would need to sell it in order to meet my desired margin of 0.1233452, or at least very close to it, let's say the price for which I will sell it will generate a margin which is max of by 0.000001 from the desired margin.

```python
optimize_fun_test(price)
s_price = 100
result = minimize(optimize_fun_test, s_price)
```

so this is what I got right now, I know it's not a lot but I don't know how to continue with the constraints.
From youtube videos I learnt that there are equality and inequality constraints, so I guess I want to have an equality constraint right ?

should the constraint look like this ?

```python
cons=({'type','eq','fun' : lambda x_start: x_start-0.1233452})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing f(x) subject to f(x) = c is the same as just solving the equation f(x) = c which in turn is equivalent to finding the root of the function q(x) = f(x) - c. Long story short, use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) instead:

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

def eq_to_solve(x):
    return optimize_fun_test(x) - 0.1233452

x0 = np.array([100.0]) # initial guess (please adapt the dimension for your problem)

sol = root(eq_to_solve, x0=x0)
```

In case you **really** want to solve it as a optimization problem (which doesn't make sense from a mathematical point of view)

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

constr = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: optimize_fun_test(x) - 0.1233452}

x0 = np.array([100.0]) # your initial guess

res = minimize(optimize_fun_test, x0=x0, constraints=constr)
```

Comment: Thanks! No this is perfectly fine. I didn't know that it doesn't make sense from a mathematical point of view.